# How to access a linux server with private IP from outside network?

Tags: linux, ip, webserver

I need to access a linux servers with private ip form any network.

Usually I use VPN to access those servers. But want to access without VPN.

Can you guys please tell the settings need to be done on server and on putty?

Thank you.

Comment: On your router forward port 22 to the private ip of the server.

Comment: @Tyson Although technically that answer is correct for SSH access, port forwarding 22 directly is a very bad and insecure idea, I have seen SSH attacks bring a server to it's knees. The better way would be to do a split forwarding, for example 65022/TCP on the outside port forwarded to 22/TCP to the inside IP address. This is still an insecure way of doing things unless you can limit access in the router to only certain IP address origination.

Comment: @acejavelin my comment wasn't meant to address security, it was meant to address the question asked.  To completely answer this question and take ALL security aspects into account can't be done in one sentence, and addressing security when it wasn't asked makes the answer opinion based.

Comment: I am having 2 network switches 1 gig and 10 gig both having private IPs.  Do I need to login to the switch to do port forwarding ?

Comment: if its web style administration, you can set your ssh connection to make a SOCKs proxy.  Then set up  your browser (firefox has been easiest for me, it just settings in 'connectivity') and then your browser will act like it is inside the private network.  You do need something with sshd running that the gateway can direct your ssh packets to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set port forwarding on the router. If it's only for access, do this for port 22 (SSH) alone. You can use another public port if you like. You only need access to one server, and can login from that server to the rest, locally. If you really need to connect to multiple servers from the outside, you have to use different ports for each of them.

If you're afraid of attacks, which will happen, you can install Fail2ban. This will block ip addresses based on failed login attempts. You can limit access on the server based on IP address. You can use private/public keys to login to SSH, or you can use something like Yubikey.

Comment: I am using public/private keys to login. How to do the port forwarding, what commands do I need to use? (don't want to mess up with my server hence asking ) ?

Comment: Port forwarding is setup in the router, not the server.